# cmake how to link external dynamic library from the static version of the samelibrary

Tags: c++, cmake

I have an external package exp1 which has both static and dynamic libraries

exp1

-- include

-- lib // 1.dll, 1.lib

Now in the cmake of the exp1 package i have added the commands

```
add_library(${XS_SHARED_LIB} SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

    set_target_properties(${XS_SHARED_LIB} PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${XS_DIR}/lib/${XS_SHARED_LIB}_1.dll
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${XS_DIR}/lib/${XS_SHARED_LIB}.lib
    )
```

Now in other external package, I am trying to link the above exp1 package statically

```
target_link_libraries(xrlib
    ${XS_SHARED_LIB}
)
```

But that is resulting linking issue with the ${XS_SHARED_LIB}_1.dll

1. error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
2. fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x360

Let me know the solution for this.

Comment: `... package exp1 which has both static and dynamic libraries` - Do the package actually has both dynamic and static libraries, or its `.lib` file just contains symbols of `.dll` file? You cannot link dynamic library using its static variant; you should have `.lib` file in form of symbols list. In other words, **static library** is **not** an **imported library**.

Comment: Please clarify whether the `.lib` is actually the import library for the dll, or a static version of that dll. Also, since you're talking about "other external package," is the variable `XS_SHARED_LIB` visible to both, and with the same contents?

Comment: I am not sure whether that is an imported version of the dll, since static library got created when dll is built. I used the same static library in another package cmake in target_link_libraries. But that is resulting in error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol . Please let me know how to create an imported static library for the dll. I am trying to find so, but not proper way to do so.